# How can I allocate 10bit values to a byte array?

Tags: c++, struct, unions

I need to send data from a microcontroller through a serial port and would like to minimize the data sent, because the data is a 10bit reading from an ADC. So I thought, I would use an union. This is what I got:

```
union fortybit
{
 struct
 {
  unsigned int a : 10;
  unsigned int b : 10;
  unsigned int c : 10;
  unsigned int d : 10;
 } tenbits;
 unsigned char bytes[5];
};
```

Now I'm sending the data like this:

```
fortybit fb;
for (int i = 0; i < 640; i++)
{
 fb.tenbits.a = 512;
 fb.tenbits.b = 512;
 fb.tenbits.c = 512;
 fb.tenbits.d = 512;
 Serial.write(fb.bytes, 5);
}
```

Which results in some strange readings, which are periodic and some of the values are right, but most of them are completely wrong.

What could I be doing wrong?
What is the right way to do this?

Comment: You're relying on undefined behaviour. That's what's wrong.

Comment: I see... I had a suspition, that it was not completely OK to do this, but how can I do it right?

Comment: type punning is rarely a good idea.

Comment: Cant you configure your serial interface object to send 10 bit words?

Comment: And I'll bet if you print out the `sizeof fb.tenbits` , you're not getting `5`

Comment: Depending on compiler, you should look at something like gcc's `__attribute__((packed))`.

Comment: as nos suggests, checking sizeof(tenbits) is a good idea.

Comment: Wow now that didn't even come to my mind... So rebel! But I guess not, I am usimg a serial->USB interface and a windows Virtual serial COM - I doubt they have this option. But I'll look into it, thanks! Otherwise I would have to send two bytes for one 10 bit value and than bitshift them together on the receiving side?

Comment: Little endian.... http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should never use bitfields in any external representation. This becomes external since you send the raw bytes where the bitfields are stored, over a serial line.

There's no way to know that the computer in the receiving end of hte serial line interprets your `struct` the same way. It might have a different byte ordering, a different native integer size into which the bits are packed which might mean different padding, or whatever.

It's simply not portable.

You should do it in a more controlled fashion, perhaps by manually computing each byte of the desired external representation. This is called *serialization*, and it's a good thing.

Comment: I'll look into this then.

Answer (score 2):

Its not like its that hard to do the packing transform yourself.
Something like this should do the trick:

```
int A[4] = { 0x1,0x1,0x1,0x1 };
int B[5];

long long x=0;
for(int i=0; i<4; i++) {
    x |= A[i] << (10*i);
}
for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
    B[i] = x & 0xFF;
    x >>= 8;
}

printf("%02x %02x %02x %02x %02x\n",B[0],B[1],B[2],B[3],B[4]);
```

Comment: Well this is a bit less complicated than what I came up with, thanks :D